# Some properties and fields are visible in the debugger but I cannot access them from the code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am wondering why I cannot access `Operands` from the code, yet it is clearly visible in the visual studio debugger?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what types these are. I assume `FilterCriteria` is some kind of interface or base class that doesn't expose `Operands`. The actual implementation of `ttt` (which implements/derives from `FilterCriteria`) does however, but since the property of `FilterControl` only exposes the interface/base class and not the concrete implementation, you can't access it.

Comment: Visual stuido debugger is smarter, hence in debug mode it shows all private and public members of a type. Even though a Type has direct or indirect access. Hence until containing type of FilterCriteria and Operands is not shown it difficult to answer. I agree with @Lennart justification too.